# Книги по программированию неориентированные на конкретный язык

Tags: книги

Меня интересуют вопрос, касающийся книг. Подскажите, какие книги должен прочитать каждый человек, чтобы стать хорошим программистом? Книги не должны быть под конкретный язык. А именно по определенным концепциям, технологиям, стилю программирования и т.д. Хотелось для себя составить список такой литературы. Прошу помощи в данном вопросе.

Уточню, именно касательно **основ**. А те кто пишут нужно много практиковаться, так практиковаться нужно основываясь на определенной теории.

Comment: Программирования без языка - это математика, логика, физика...

Answer (score 4):

"Совершенный код" С.Макконнел, Р.Мартин "Чистый код" - хорошие книги о правильном стиле написания кода.

А вообще Вы претендуете получить **очень** длинный список литературы. Во-первых, потому что сколько людей - столько и мнений. Каждый будет ту или иную книгу хорошей, а другого человека будет диаметрально противоположное мнение.

Во-вторых, тема достаточно широкая....вот например архитектура процессоров, мат.основы (например, для криптографии), архитектура сетей, бд, методы построения компьютерной графики, всевозможные алгоритмы, паттерны....можно продолжать ещё долго...являются ли эти темы "смежными" с программированием?Вы можете превратиться в "вечного студента", если попытаетесь всё это освоить...в стремлении стать "хорошим программистом".

Comment: "Совершенный код" С.Макконнел - очень рекомендую. Книга сильная, но довольно растянутая. Примеры на разных языках.
Р.Мартин "Чистый код" - она с примерами целиком на яве.

Answer (score 3):

А как вы представляете себе программирование с отрывом от языка программирования?)
Бенджамин Пирс "Типы в языках программирования" - недавно перевели ее оенсорсно, кажется. Сам не читал пока что. Там много математики.
Мартин Файлер "Рефакторинг. Улучшение уществующего кода" - примеры на яве.

"97 Things Every Programmer Should Know"
"What Every Programmer Should Know About Memory"

Еще одна книга была по функциональному программированию, с примерами на Шеме, по которой начинаю преподавать программинг в МИТе, но название сейчас не вспомню. Говорят, после нее понятны любые языки программирования)

Comment: и моя мысль такая - что бы стать хорошим программистом, нужно писать много кода, проходить много код ревью, причем у людей, которые знают больше вас. Просто читая ничего не выйдет, я это понял на себе. В "Совершенном коде" есть целая глава как стать программистом получше

Comment: SICP - http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book.html

Comment: SICP -- ее и имел ввиду) А по какой литературе pythonучат? Странно, почему python

Comment: Introduction to Computer Science and Programming/[readings][1]

  [1]: http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-00-introduction-to-computer-science-and-programming-fall-2008/readings/

Answer (score 2):

Искусство программирования, автор Дональд Кнут (4-ре тома)